# C#: Log In History of Windows7 machine

Tags: c#, wpf, console-application

This might seem a strange idea so bear with me.

Every day (Mon-Fri), I wake up, go to work and log in on my PC. I was wondering if it is possible to pull up the details of each log in (mainly I'm interested in the date and the exact time). Then, having such information, I can plot it out on a chart and some interesting patterns might come out. For example, I've noticed that on Mondays I tend to go to work earlier than any other day of the week :) (yeah, I know, resting during the weekends might be the reason).

Anyway, if anyone knows a way to pull out the log ins on a certain PC and read them in a C# application (WPF, Console etc.) would be great. What would be event greater is if there was some C# library which might alleviate the process.

Any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Best Regards,

Monthy

Comment: BTW, there's no 'h' in "Monty Python"

Comment: Save yourself the bother and install something like [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com) or [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com) instead - they both do what you want. I would recommend ManicTime as it plots lots of very useful graphs, including one showing working hours over time.

Comment: @Mitch: "Monty Pyt*h*on" :) My comment also pays homage to the famous [argument sketch](http://www.davidpbrown.co.uk/jokes/monty-python-arguement.html) - I guess tongue-in-cheek is hard to get across on the internet.

Comment: @ adrianbanks: yeah, mine too! ;)

Comment: But seriously, there's no 'h' in "Monty"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get it from Windows Event Log
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6b9a7h8.aspx
then filter for log on/log off event.

Anyway, I think writing program that runs every time you log-on (auto-startup) and logs the time you log-on and log-off is easier.

For statistic purpose, you can try [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. The RescueTime link (http://www.rescuetime.com/xxJEsIhOCtpT1_M_TMsyA&cad=rja) appears to be broken.

Comment: Edited :). the latter part of the link is just useless

Answer (score 2):

You could try pulling the data out of the [Event Log](http://www.windows7update.com/Windows7-Event-Viewer.html).

.NET Framework offer classes to access the Event Log programmatically. Start from the MSDN article on [EventLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx) class.